# Visual Studio C# SQLProj - Throwing errors

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlproj

I have a Visual Studio SQLProj that throws errors automatically when synching with the database. Not sure why this is happening when the DB is not throwing any errors at all.

For instance I have a username that called [datawriter]

When clicking on it I see the following code:

```
CREATE LOGIN [datawriter]
```

Not sure how this user works in the db but not in the project. Any idea how to fix this for good. Do I need to fix this in the db?

We should not see any errors when synching with the db.

Comment: do you use sysadmin?can you tell me permission of your user?only you can't sync user or other thing(data,login,schema,....)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it like this:

```
CREATE LOGIN [datawriter]
FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english];
GO

CREATE USER [datawriter] FOR LOGIN [datawriter];
GO
```